# CSS opacity hover is delayed when no padding

Tags: html, css, hover, padding, opacity

> ```
> <style>
> .test{ background-color: green; opacity: 0; filter: alpha(opacity=0); padding: 0px; }
> .test:hover{ opacity: 0.6; filter: alpha(opacity=60); }
> </style>
>
> <a class="test">test</a>
> ```

I am trying to get the link's opacity to 0.6 when hovered and disappear (opacity to 0) "immediately" when mouseout.

With the code above, there is a slight delay when mouseout before it disappears. It's very odd because it disappears immediately if I add 3px padding to class test. Anything lesser than 3px does not work.

Why is the padding affecting the timing of the opacity? How do I make it disappear "immediately" without changing the padding?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Let me guess - this only occurs in Internet Explorer, not in FF or Chrome?

Comment: This code was tested in FF 21.0 :)

Comment: [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/EKKvJ/) does not reproduce your issue in FF21 or Chrome latest beta.

Comment: @stackker Clean up your browser cache/history and then try to test it again

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I have just updated the fiddle, you left the <style></style> on the css hence it wasn't showing properly. Have a look again :) you gotta hover on the top left of the last box to see the green link because opacity was set to 0 at beginning.

Comment: Oops, [fixed it](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/EKKvJ/3/), but I still don't see an issue in FF nor Chrome, with padding set to `0` or `3px` it's both instant as it should.

Comment: @dhavalmarthak ahh, I clear up the browser cache/history and it works like normal again. Wonder why the cache creates the delay though. Cheers.

Comment: Should have been an answer :) :) :)